# Error on Updating Android Studio 4.1. and getting error for using TargetSDK Version 29

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Today I updated my Android Studio to 4.1 and I got many errors in
after running flutter Doctor I found this. And please also tell me how to update SDK version 29.

[image]

I have tried to update my Android SDK Version to 29 and tried many answer of stackoverflow and github but can not solve this problem.

I have installed flutter and dart plugin and also project is running but flutter doctor not found the location of flutter and dart plugins.

[image]

and After changing the targetSdk version to 29 from 28 I am getting this error.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 29 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 29 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 29 (revision: 5)".
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
  The SDK directory is not writable (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I tried almost every solution from old answers on stackoverflow and github but nothing worked for me.

Comment: *The SDK directory is not writable (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk)* ...what do you not understand? with basic Windows OS knowladge you should know that you know admin rights ... Did you read this at least?

Comment: Now what should I do to get the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

My error.

[image: my error]

I solved my issue with dart and flutter plugins issue  by running:

```
flutter channel dev

flutter upgrade

flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"

flutter doctor -v
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens with the new Android Studio Version 4.1 not fully supported for flutter sdk  1.20.xx try to upgrade your flutter sdk with `flutter upgrde`,
Flutter is already up to date on channel stable
the latest version is 1.22.xx.

or you can use Flutter 1.23.xx on channel dev. There's no problem with Flutter 1.23.xx